# Why did this edit go through the review queue?

Tags: bug, status-completed

Yesterday, the author of: [Volume representation of ring distribution (cylindrical coordinates)](https://stats.stackexchange.com/q/217751/7290) attempted to edit his own question ([edit 4 in the revision history](https://stats.stackexchange.com/revisions/217751/4)).  Instead of going through, the edit went through the suggested edit queue ([record](https://stats.stackexchange.com/review/suggested-edits/105964)) with the comment,

> Answered some questions in the post because I can't comment.

What is important here is that the editor was the OP.  He should have been able to edit his own Q without needing approval.  This often happens because an OP has multiple (typically unregistered) accounts.  However, that was not the case here.  The OP and the editor had the same usernumber [119177](https://stats.stackexchange.com/users/119177/billyziege?tab=topactivity), and he earned [+2 reputation](https://stats.stackexchange.com/users/119177/billyziege?tab=reputation) for having his edit accepted.

What happened here?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The user actually had two profiles created by mistake and proposed the edit from the other profile, not the one used to ask the question.

The profiles have since been merged, so now the edit looks a bit weird, but there's no issue here otherwise.

Comment: When I saw it in the queue, the user numbers were the same. So the idea is that the accounts were merged in between when the edit was suggested & it was reviewed, but that merging didn't kick it back out of the queue?

Comment: @gung Right. This is a very rare case and there's no actual harm from leaving the edit still in the queue.